# Python - Expanding a group using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to python and I'm trying to automate a few tasks.

My issue is when I log in to my server I need to expand the group and select the form inside the group, I'm using find_element By Xpath and ID and keep getting this error "Unable to locate element:", I tried to use sleep or WebDriverWait but didn't work.

My element code in image now (the arrow):

When I open it manual the aria-expanded changed to ="true"

My group code:

[Main group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHL4l.png)

[Forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIHV2.png)

---

The website login details (dummy server):
server: https://new2001.surveycto.com/
user: taevion.ezrael@alldrys.com
password: Stackoverflow_example

Comment: These images would not help much. Please post the code that you tried and/or the html code in question, and if possible, the website link for easy inspection. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I added the login information to the question.

Comment: Thanks @Emad. I have added answer based on the query you have provided. Check and let me know if this what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.get(" https://new2001.surveycto.com/")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "login-username").send_keys("taevion.ezrael@alldrys.com")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Next']").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "login-password").send_keys("Stackoverflow_example")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Log in']").click()
time.sleep(10)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//*[@data-form-field-id='foundation'])[1]")).perform()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//*[@data-form-field-id='foundation'])[1]//button[@data-original-title='Add form, group or dataset']").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//*[@data-form-field-id='foundation'])[1]//div[@class='primary-actions']//a[contains(@data-original-title, 'start from scratch')]").click()
time.sleep(5)
x = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//form[@method='post']//h3").text
print(x)
driver.save_screenshot('snapshot.png')
driver.quit()
```

This code logs in to the website with the credentials and then clicks on the `+` icon of the Foundation form, and after the expansion occurs, it clicks on the `Start New Form` button, and just to verify for you, it takes the snapshot of the screen and extracts the form header.

Output:

```
Start new form - Step 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[Form Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFTnc.png)

Comment: Hi Anand, thank you it worked, but i have to ask you how did you get these xpaths, because when i click on the element and copy the xpath i get another one for example when i select the (+)_ and copy the xpath this is what i get "//*[@id="id-add-item-panel-1644398283997"]/div[1]/button"

Comment: And one more question, how to close the group (hide the foundation group), press the arrows to close the group.

Comment: @Emad, I do not rely on any xpath-building tools. I make my own xpaths, and I search for a near robust one. Google out on how to build robust xpath for selenium, and you'd get a lot of material to read and apply. Good luck!

Comment: Try this to close arrow:
`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='dsg-group-cont__marker-bottom-panel-right'])[1]").click()`